# What's to keep Wayward Pines humans from evolving into Abbies?

Tags: wayward-pines

In the series Wayward Pines, the premise is that man has evolved into this terrible beast called "Abbie", and that Wayward Pines is an "ark" of humans preserved 2000 years in order to  repopulate the earth. Won't the preserved humans also, over the next 2000 years, evolve into Abbies, making the whole exercise pointless?

Answer (score 8):

Wayward Pines exists when it does because this is when the environmental changes that evolved humans into Abbies have reversed sufficiently for humans to stay human again.  So the Wayward Pines inhabitants are safe from their descendents becoming Abbies.

This is essentially what Pilcher's breakthrough was, he predicted that the environmental changes would in turn change humanity.  He then modeled when the changes humans made in the environment would naturally reverse themselves, and that's when the inhabitants of Wayward Pines (and its support infrastructure) would awaken to start anew.

Comment: So basically, Wayward Pines is almost a live action Fall Out? Damn vault dwellers

Comment: Or similar to Pandorum

Answer (score 6):

I know nothing about Wayward Pines, but I can still answer the question: No. That's not how evolution works.

A species diverges and becomes a new species due to

- what environmental factors were in place during it's speciation (which is fairly unlikely to be repeated)
- what exact random mutations and recombinations of genes came about (astronomically unlikely to be repeated)
- which individuals mated with which other individuals and which were randomly killed off before they could produce offspring (impossible to repeat).

Given all this, it is literally impossible to repeat evolution of a specific species.

This is really another version of the classic "If humans evolved from monkeys why are there still monkeys?" question.  Lots of good info on that:

- https://www.icr.org/article/3109/
- http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/How_come_there_are_still_monkeys%3F

If this doesn't make sense to you, a similar question would be: why don't the British have American accents?

Comment: Given that it only took 2000 years for them to evolve like that, we can throw real world evolution out the window.  -1 for not even attempting to answer in universe

Comment: I feel you @cde.  Still worth leaving here as a point of education, since pop sci-fi in general seems to run wild with the concept of evolution.

Comment: "why don't the British have American accents" -- ah, finally, Wayward Pines makes sense to me. The Abbies are *Americans*. Ruthless, effective survivors but none too smart and you wouldn't invite one to dine. And Pilcher's volunteers are the British: intelligent, arrogant, privileged, seek control over unsuspecting populations despite filling their very patchy competence as rulers with gratuitous displays of brutality, fundamentally doomed, but at least have decent table manners. Yes, as it happens, I'm British. Why do you ask?

Comment: Ah, British insecurity. Never goes out of style.

Answer (score 1):

The humans in the experiment wouldn't turn into abbies because the humans that weren't on the ark were exposed to the pollution cuasing them to evolve, where as the ones on the ark were in the stilled animation chambers, keeping them safe from the evolution.

Answer (score -2):

You are making the **HUGE** assumption that what the agent saw in regards to Abbies was in fact reality.

### In Universe

Several references have been dropped that Nurse Patty can alter people's memories.  Furthermore, no involved in revealing that information to the Agent seems trustworthy.  Therefore it is highly likely that something about the Abbies is incorrect (maybe their existance?).

### Out of Universe

M. Night Shyamalan has a history of stories with multiple plot twists.  It's too early in this story for the final reveal.  So I am looking at the in-story bread crumbs mentioned above and am entirely convinced we *still* don't know what is going on in Wayward Pines.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, but I am starting to form the opinion that if "planet full of Abbies" is actually the truth then there's literally no point watching the rest of the show. But even if the Abbies are an in-fiction fiction, there's an in-in-fiction-fiction answer to the question ;-)